# List email address in a field (xcode 4)

Tags: objective-c, list, xcode4

I would like to make a field (containing a list of email address) with a plus button. This button opens the contact list and when I select the contact, lemail of this one ranks in my fields.

In fact, I wish the same interface as MFMailComposeViewController but just for the recipient field. thank you.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a good learning project. Lots of helpful info here on SO.

Comment: You need to describe your questions in a better way to get any help. You can post images, code etc to support your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look up `UITableView` for how to make a list of email addresses you can interact with. For sending an email you can use `MessageUI`.

You'll need to make a view controller set as the delegate and data source for your table view. Then override `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to display email addresses and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to open up an email dialogue. To send email you'd use something like

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailController setSubject:@"Subject"];
    [mailController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
    [mailController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
}
```

Once you have something to show, feel free to come back with any errors or specific questions you have. Just remember that SO is not a place where we make free code for you, but we are happy to help you with your problems.